# Weka - Run K-Means++ Algorithm in JAVA code to preserve memory

Tags: clustering, large-data, weka

Anyone know how to run weka k-means++ clustering source directly in JAVA code to preserve memory? 
I load and run k-means++ clustering for large datasets (6 millions) in weka but always freeze, i try increase heap_size, convert datasets to sparse .arff, run in knowledge flow but that makes no difference. i know there is more scale able k-means++ it call k-means||, but run parallel clustering is the last option for me because i don't have enough resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run all Weka algorithms from **command line** instead of using the GUI. But I doubt this will ultimately resolve your memory problems. Nor will using Java - you won't save *any* memory by calling it from Java as opposed to the Weka command line.

Try the following in order:

- reduce your data set size. k-means quality increases only very little with excessive data.
- limit the number of iterations. 10 may be good enough.
- try ELKI. it is similar to Weka, but uses much less memory and is a lot faster.
- try efficient C implementations - Java will always need more memoey than well optimized C code
- roll your own C implementation, optimized for your data

Comment: Thank you @Anony-Mousse, for enlighten me...
According this site [link] (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/bigdata.html) Weka Simple CLI, knowledge flow and use java-base scripting is the best way dealing with large datasets, i would prefer use knowledge flow because more user friendly, but still, it takes long time to process huge datasets, I've tried data dan dimension reduction, but my result will not comprehensive anymore. 
is there any link that i could use to learn weka simple CLI and ELKI for clustering? in ELKI there is cluster analysis/evaluation and visualization too, right?

Comment: Weka commandline does not need a manual, nor does ELKI. In the UI you will see the exact command line parameters you need later; just call the Weka jar with the class you want, or ELKI with "cli" Parameter. Yes, ELKI is has everything for clustering, also many more algorithms than Weka. Just try it.